# Update ASP.NET web.config while still in process of client request

Tags: asp.net, web-config

What happen if web.config gets updated while ASP (ASP.NET 2.0) server still process client request? 
- Will the process be killed?
- If not, will the process read the updates in web.config.

thanks for any input

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new `web.config` is effectively a copy, so an ongoing request will finish unaffected -- it will not pick up the changes. When the request is complete, the new `web.config` will be written over the old one and subsequent requests will work from the updated values (in a new application domain).

Answer (score 5):

### Microsoft: *"ASP.NET will serve all pending requests before restart"*

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx

> When an application restart is
>   required, ASP.NET will serve all
>   pending requests from the existing
>   application domain and the old
>   assemblies before restarting the
>   application domain and loading the new
>   assemblies.

and following the flow of logic through changes to the asp.net Web.config file ...

---

**"Configuration Changes Cause a Restart of the Application Domain"**

The app effectively restarts. However there is also a trick noted in this first blurb to work around that "issue".

> **Changes to configuration settings in
>   Web.config files *indirectly* cause the
>   application domain to restart.** This
>   behavior occurs by design. You can
>   optionally use the configSource
>   attribute to reference external
>   configuration **files that do not cause
>   a restart** when a change is made. For
>   more information, see configSource in
>   General Attributes Inherited by
>   Section Elements.
>
> Attempts to change a configuration
>   file by someone who does not have
>   permission to edit the file will not
>   cause a restart of the application
>   domain.

^-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ackhksh7.aspx

### Loss of State

Your application, session and other states will be lost if stored in process ...

> When using the in-process
>   session-state mode, session-state data
>   is lost if **aspnet_wp.exe or the
>   application domain restarts**.

^-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87069683(VS.71).aspx

> The life-cycle implications of
>   information stored in **application
>   state**. The .NET Framework application
>   domain or the process hosting a
>   .NET-based application can be torn
>   down and destroyed at any moment
>   during application execution (as a
>   result of crashes, code updates,
>   scheduled process **restarts**, and so
>   on).

^-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf9xhdz4(VS.71).aspx

---

**Etc...**
Just some miscellanei. Info about storing session state out of process.

^-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Comment: Definitely very true and good citations, I responded to a poster asking how to make a button to restart their web app and told them they want it to just update the web.config and got DVs for it!

Comment: I prefer protecting web.config from writes and telling user to instead write/kick the external config file 'external.config' linked into Web.config as: <section name="mine" type="y" restartOnExternalChanges="true" />
|and| <mine configSource="myexternal.config"></mine>

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you make any changes to web.config, ASP.NET automatically reloads your application by recycling the application pool.  This of course will result in Session, Application, and Cache data of an InProc session state being lost.

Comment: Note that you can see this by simply making some trivial modification to the web.config in your text editor while your app is running and then saving it back to disk.

Answer (score 0):

The AppDomain will be unloaded after the request finishes.

Comment: So the request will still be processed, and response will be sent back to client correct until next request, is that right?